# Why are the items in my collection not displaying on the page? (Meteor)

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

Here is my Meteor Code:

```
Template.home.events({
'submit #ask-question': function(e,t) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var subject = t.find("#subjectinput").value;
  var question = t.find("#questioninput").value;

  Questions.insert({
    subject: subject,
    question: question,
    createdAt: new Date()
  });
}
});

Template.home.helpers({
questions: function() {
  return Questions.find({});
}
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<ul>
  {{#each Questions}}
    {{> question}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Shouldn't it just iterate over the collection and display each one?
(Btw, I have a template names question created, so that isn't the problem either)

Comment: Please post your publication and subscription for the Questions collection.  Or are you using the `insecure` package?

Comment: `$ meteor add autopublish` - if you see data with that package installed then you're missing your publication, subscription, or both.

Comment: Or just write `Questions.find({}).count();` in the console. If it's 0, then it's subscriptions / allow rules.

Comment: @challett What's publication and subscription?

Comment: @HubertOG It says 12

Comment: Oh duh, capitalization. You've got `{{#each Questions}}` but your helper is `questions`

Answer (score 1):

update your template to following

```
<ul>
  {{#each questions}}
    {{> question}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```